# Need some help building first simple jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build my first jQuery plug-in yet it's proving to be more difficult than I thought.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this where you name the selector and pass how many items should be in a row.

```
$('#photo-gallery').grid(3);
```

Then the plugin function would select the nth-child(Xn) of the direct child elements of #photo-gallery where X is the option passed in above. In this case, the number is 3.

I'd like to also have it select the direct children of the original selector, #photo-gallery, so if I've got divs, list items, anchors tags, or whatever as direct children of #photo-gallery, those are the elements that nth-child(Xn) is applied to.

This is what I have with just basic jQuery, but I'm in the dark as to how to convert this into a plugin.

```
$('#photo-gallery div:nth-child(3n)').addClass("end-row-grid-item");
$('#photo-gallery div:nth-child(3n+1)').addClass("new-row-grid-item");
```

As far as the plugin goes, here is what I have so far...

```
(function($){

    $.fn.extend({

        //pass the options variable to the function
        grid: function(options) {


            //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                gridItems: 3
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {

            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Like I said, I'm completely in the dark as to how to pass my selector and option in to complete the plugin.

Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's really all the jQuery you need to make the effects, it might not be necessary to make a plugin... If you do want to, have a go with this:

```
$.fn.grid = function(count) {
    this.children(':nth-child(' + count + 'n)').addClass('end-row-grid-item');
    this.children(':nth-child(' + count + 'n+1)').addClass('new-row-grid-item');
};
```

This isn't exactly the same as the code example you give. It only selects direct child nodes and it selects them whatever kind of element they are. This seems to be what you need.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should clear it up for you how to make parameters for your plugin:

```
$(function () {


        $.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

            var settings = {
                'foo': 'bar'
            };

            return this.each(function () {
                // If options exist, lets merge them
                // with our default settings
                if (options) {
                    $.extend(settings, options);
                }

                alert(settings.foo);


            });
        };


        $('p').click(function () {
            $(this).myPlugin({ foo: 'dd' });
        });

    });
```

The parameters in the settings will be your default parameters until they are set when the pluin is called. once they are set, they will override the initial value. So this one will alert dd

Comment: Thanks XGreen. Its good to see the different ways this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as what was already posted...

```
(function($) {
  return $.fn.grid = function(params) {
    params = $.extend({
      gridItems: 3
    }, params);
    this.find(":nth-child(" + gridItems + "n)").addClass("end-row-grid-item");
    this.find(":nth-child(" + gridItems + "n+1)").addClass("new-row-grid-item");
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

or in coffeescript

```
($) ->

  $.fn.grid = (params) ->

    params = $.extend gridItems: 3, params

    @find(":nth-child(#{gridItems}n)").addClass("end-row-grid-item")
    @find(":nth-child(#{gridItems}n+1)").addClass("new-row-grid-item")
    this
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know there are multiple ways to get from point A to point B so it's nice to see these other solutions!